# background-size: cover is not covering the div but it overflown

Tags: html, css

[image]

If you see the image of mine where i gave the same style as told in youtube video and in that video the image is covered the div width and height

But when i tried the same my image is overflown instead of cover exactly to the div dimensions

why it has happened to my code but not for him in the video?`

```css
#service-image {
  height: 400px;
  width: 70%;
  
  background: url("../images/lesson\ img-2.jpg");
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
  /* background-size: 50px 100px;  */
  /* background-size: contain; */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="service-image"></div>

    <h2 class="subtitle">Contact Us</h2>
    
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="input-form">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="input-form">
      <textarea></textarea>
      <button>Submit</button>   
    </form>
```

`

Comment: read what cover means: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#values

Comment: it's already cover, it takes all the div width and height, try to resize your div and the picture will get bigger

Comment: okay understood that if the proportions of the background differ from the element, the image is cropped either vertically or horizontally.

But why was it happened to me but not to the person in the video when i used the same code as he used in video

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to use `background-image:url(sth);width:100%` and then give this style to not to overflow `overflow:hidden;` or if you want to show overflow with scroll `overflow:scroll;`